# Dynamically connect to different DB if one fails in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, flask, connection

I want to find a way where I can dynamically be connected to secondary DB if primary DB is timed out. I've reserarched extensively and found some solutions that uses only the SQLAlchemy not the Flask-SQLAlchemy. The recommended solution was like below.

```
engine1 = create_engine(...)
engine2 = create_engine(...)
Session1 = sessionmaker(bind=engine1)
Session2 = sessionmaker(bind=engine2)
session1 = scoped_session(Session1, scopefunc=...)
session2 = scoped_session(Session2, scopefunc=...)
```

And I want to build a fail safe something like below.. the synthax is in psuedo code.

```
if not request_has_connection:
   db = SQLAlchemy(app) # instantiate db with different config that has different db URI.
```

The problem is that, Flask-SQLAlchemy does not allow users to separately instantiate engine, the db that is used by every model is all instantiated from one line which is  `db=SQLAlchemy(app)`

How can I dynamically change the URI of the database to secondary if the primary has timedout or if it lost its connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into application factories [(here)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/)? if you bind your app instance to your db using the lazy method then you can load a different configuration object / file. Not sure what your project structure is really like right now - but something like

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

and then after you do

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
```

Check out this [(here)](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/22/) flask snippet on a Lazy SQLAlchemy setup.